# how to get delivery status of message in smack or in xmpp from android

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

This is my code and i am sending my message in this method but not able to get delivery message in DeliveryReceipt

```
    newChat.sendMessage(message);
            newChat.getListeners();
            newChat.addMessageListener(new ChatMessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"DeliveryReceipt3:"+"1:"+message.getThread()+"2:"+chat.getThreadID()+"3:"+message.getBody());
                }
            });
```

the above code is for sending message and below code is for getting DeliveryReceipt

```
   Message m = new Message();
                m.setType(Message.Type.chat);
                m.setFrom(connection.getUser());
                m.setTo(agentId);
                m.addExtension(new DeliveryReceipt(m.getPacketID()));

                DeliveryReceipt dr = (DeliveryReceipt)m.getExtension(DeliveryReceipt.ELEMENT, DeliveryReceipt.NAMESPACE);
                Log.d(TAG,"DeliveryReceipt1: "+"1:"+dr.getElementName()+"2:"+dr.getId()+"3:"+dr.getNamespace()+"4:"+dr.toXML()+"4:"+dr.toString());
                Log.d(TAG,"DeliveryReceipt2: "+"1:"+m.getBody()+"2:"+m.getStanzaId()+"3:"+m.getThread());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get delivery status of recent messages in smack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286752/get-delivery-status-of-recent-messages-in-smack)

Answer (score 2):

you need to add  DeliveryReceiptManager after you successfully logs in

```
DeliveryReceiptManager dm = DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
                    dm.setAutoReceiptMode(AutoReceiptMode.always);
                    dm.autoAddDeliveryReceiptRequests();
                    dm.addReceiptReceivedListener(new ReceiptReceivedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onReceiptReceived(Jid fromJid, Jid toJid, 
                      final String receiptId, Stanza receipt) {
                             // handle delivery receipt here
                            }
                      });
```

Comment: Thanks, this has been helpful, configuring dm.setAutoReceiptMode(AutoReceiptMode.always); did it for me

Answer (score 1):

First add these to your configuration-

```
DeliveryReceiptManager.setDefaultAutoReceiptMode(DeliveryReceiptManager.AutoReceiptMode.always);
ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(DeliveryReceipt.ELEMENT, DeliveryReceipt.NAMESPACE, new DeliveryReceipt.Provider());
ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(DeliveryReceiptRequest.ELEMENT, DeliveryReceipt.NAMESPACE, new DeliveryReceiptRequest.Provider());
```

Then after XMPPTcpConnection established add these-

```
DeliveryReceiptManager deliveryReceiptManager = DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(this.connection);
deliveryReceiptManager.setAutoReceiptMode(DeliveryReceiptManager.AutoReceiptMode.always);
deliveryReceiptManager.autoAddDeliveryReceiptRequests();
```

This will enable delivery receipt for all messages.

```
SENT:
<iq to='chat_host' id='o2huU-440' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>

RECV:
<iq from='chat_host'id='o2huU-440' to='userJID'type='result'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'> <feature var='urn:xmpp:receipts'/></query>
```

For auto receipt mode all message will be sent with a receipt request extension. And you will get delivery receipt for all messages.

Comment: Could you please correct me,  how to add receipt request to message : 
msg.addExtension( DeliveryReceipt(msg.stanzaId));