# JXMPP & smack Android Library, Get Message Delivery Status

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, messaging, smack

Em working on Chatting Application and everything is working perfectly, Now I want to check either my messages has been DELIVERED or SEEN by the receiver or not. For that purpose Em using DeliveryReceiptRequest of XMPP Library, I got the RequestID of the Message. But Em not sure how to get status by this ID. Can you please help me out? I want to finish it within next few hours.

Ask Questions whatever you want to Ask. I'll reply you instantly.

```
private void sendMessage(final String messageId, final String jid, final String content, final int chatType, final boolean isSticker) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Message message;
                Log.e("Send SMS" , "Step 4");

                try {
                    message = new Message(JidCreate.from(jid), content);
                    String deliveryReceiptId = DeliveryReceiptRequest.addTo(message);
                    Log.e("Numan Special", "sendMessage: deliveryReceiptId for this message is: " + deliveryReceiptId);
                    manageBoBExtension(message);
                } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Send SMS" , "Step 7");
                    mListener.onError(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    return;
                }

                message.setStanzaId(messageId);
                sendMessageDependingOnType(message, jid, chatType);
            }

            private void manageBoBExtension(Message message) {
                if (isSticker) {
                    Log.e("Send SMS" , "Step 5");
                    BoBHash bobHash = new BoBHash(Base64.encode(content), "base64");
                    message.addExtension(new BoBExtension(bobHash, null, null));
                }
                Log.e("Send SMS" , "Step 6");
            }
        }).start();
    }



private void sendMessageDependingOnType(Message message, String jid, int chatType) {
        if (chatType == Chat.TYPE_MUC_LIGHT) {
            MultiUserChatLightManager manager = XMPPSession.getInstance().getMUCLightManager();

            try {
                MultiUserChatLight multiUserChatLight = manager.getMultiUserChatLight(JidCreate.from(jid).asEntityBareJidIfPossible());
                multiUserChatLight.sendMessage(message);
            } catch (XmppStringprepException | InterruptedException | SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                mListener.onError(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            } finally {
                mListener.onMessageSent(message);
            }

        } else {
            ChatManager chatManager = RoomsListManager.getInstance().getChatManager();
            try {
                chatManager.createChat(JidCreate.from(jid).asEntityJidIfPossible()).sendMessage(message);
            } catch (InterruptedException | XmppStringprepException | SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                mListener.onError(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            } finally {
                mListener.onMessageSent(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get delivery status of recent messages in smack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286752/get-delivery-status-of-recent-messages-in-smack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before sending the message Add `DeliveryReceiptRequest.addTo(yourMsg)` after receiving Message on the other end send another xmpp Message using `message.addExtension(new DeliveryReceipt(packet.getStanzaId))`  then listen for updated status by implementing `ReceiptReceivedListener`. Also you can refer official Documentation [here](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html)